# How can I use `&` in an alias

Tags: command-line, alias

I want to add an alias for nedit editor

```
alias ne='nedit' 
or 
alias ne='nedit $1'
```

works fine

but i want to add `&` at its end:

```
alias ne='nedit $1 &'
```

so that if i do

```
ne filename
```

It should open `filename` in nedit and run it in background

but I get an error

```
filename : command not found
```

How can I pass an argument and send the process to the background using aliases?

Comment: As far as I know, `alias`, just replaces “ne” with “nedit”, you can't pass arguments to it. `$1` in `alias ne='nedit $1'` is just ignored, if you want to keep it in the background, how about `ne filename &`?

Comment: You have to use functions instead: `function ne(){ nedit $1 & };`.

Comment: @dessert that won't solve the purpose

Comment: @ra-one You're right that it doesn't solve your problem, see Ravexina's comment for a solution, but it nevertheless answers the questions whether `alias` can be used with `&` at the end.

Comment: @Ravexina its working :)

Comment: @dessert ya correct